# EventListener or explicit infinite loop

Tags: java, events

I have code inside an infinite loop which checks to see if a specific IP address is reachable. If the IP address is reachable, some logic is executed (say sending email). All this resides in a infinite loop which is running in a separate thread (meant to do just this).

**Question:** Should this be kept as-is i.e. keep the code running infinitely in it's own thread OR should I be creating an EventListener? The reason I'm confused is because even if I create an EventListener I will need to keep checking if the IP address is reachable which has to be in an infinite loop, correct?

Edit: As requested(@M. Suurland) the sample code is as below:

```
public class FindingIP {

// The creating thread will actually be part of a servlet call
public static void main(String[] args){
 // do something....
 //creating thread to search for a device
 Thread findingIPAliveThread = new Thread(new FindingIPAlive());
 findingIPAliveThread.start();
 // do something....
  }
 }



public class FindingIPAlive implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
    try {
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
        if (ip.isReachable(2000))
            //do some action
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}

}
```

As mentioned by @Dawnkeeper, I have also tried triggering like below too:

```
FindingIPAlive findIP = new FindingIPAlive();
ScheduledExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors .newScheduledThreadPool(1);
taskExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(findIP, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But I was curious to know if in this scenario it would be feasible to create EventListener and if yes, should it be created.

Comment: post the code please

Comment: @M.Suurland - Updated the code above

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything negative about using an endless loop.

A cleaner looking alternative could be:

```
void java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

Docs see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-)